# Read return values of a Firebird stored procedure

Tags: c++, stored-procedures, firebird, c++builder

I have this Firebird stored procedure:

```
SET TERM ^ ;
CREATE PROCEDURE MYSP ( FIRSTPARAM Varchar(3) )
    RETURNS ( ERROR Varchar(128) )
AS BEGIN
    /* a lot of things, including setting a value to ERROR */
    suspend;
END^
SET TERM ; ^
```

I need to execute this procedure in C++ Builder XE2 and finally read its return value (`ERROR`) to see if it succeded. Procedure returns only one row.

I tried this way:

```
TIBQuery* q = DMH->ordQuery;
q->Close( );
q->SQL->Clear( );
q->SQL->Text = "EXECUTE PROCEDURE MYSP(:P1)";

if ( !DMH->ordTrans->InTransaction )
{
    MakeCommit = true;
    DMH->ordTrans->StartTransaction( );
}
if ( !q->Prepared )
    q->Prepare( );

q->Params->ParamByName( "P1" )->Value = "abc";
q->Open();

//success if error field contains NULL
TField* errorField = q->FieldByName( "ERROR" );
bool success = errorField->IsNull;

if ( MakeCommit )
    DMH->ordTrans->Commit( );
```

It gives me an access violation on `errorField`, because it can't find such field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to change the statement:

```
SELECT ERROR
FROM MYSP(:P1)
```

Comment: That is because when you use `SUSPEND` in a stored procedure it is selectable and not executable; if you remove the `SUSPEND` your original code it might work (although I have to admit I am not 100% sure).

Comment: @MarkRotteveel thanks for your confirmation. Anyway removing `SUSPEND` and using `EXECUTE PROCEDURE MYSP(:P1)` it does not work, neither `FieldByName` nor `Params->ParamByName`.

Comment: It looks like you need to use `TIB_DSQL` for executable procedures: http://web.firebirdsql.org/index.php?op=useful&id=Connectivity#ibo_dsql (I don't know how old this is though and if it is the same connection library)

Comment: An `EXECUTE` statement returns the return value like a normal function would. It is not a field in the SQL result set. In Firebird, the [`EXECUTE` statement](http://www.firebirdsql.org/refdocs/langrefupd15-execproc.html) has a `returning_values` clause where you specify the variable(s) that receive the return value(s). You can then `SELECT` the variable(s), or alternatively use a `FOR SELECT ... INTO` statement. [See examples](http://web.firebirdsql.org/dotnetfirebird/blog/2006/03/calling-stored-procedures-from-stored.html)